# Use a Batch File to list files and allow the user to select which file to copy into a new destination

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am a newbie to Windows Scripting.
I am trying to list some txt files in several sub directories & want to copy a user selected file to a new destination. Please note that the file name is unique in different locations.
I got the first part to work (Listing out the files & locations) using the following script, but I am unable to copy the selected file to the new location.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET index=1

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

SET FFPath="C:\Scripts - Backup Server\DKXpress_bkp"
SET NewPath=C:\DKServer

ECHO Recursively searching %FFPath% 
echo.

FOR /F "delims=" %%f in ('DIR %FFPath%\*.txt /a:-d /s /b') DO (
SET file!index!=%%f
ECHO !index! - %%f
SET /A index=!index!+1
)

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /P selection="select file by number:"

SET file%selection% >nul 2>&1

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
ECHO invalid number selected   
EXIT /B 1

)

SET NewFile=file%selection%

ECHO Copying %NewFile% to %NewPath%
ECHO.
COPY /Y "%NewFile%" "%NewPath%"
ECHO. 
PAUSE
```

I think I am doing this part wrong

```
SET NewFile=file%selection%
```

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set an index variable or delayed expansion, if you let `Find` do the work for you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "FFPath=C:\Scripts - Backup Server\DKXpress_bkp"
Set "NewPath=C:\DKServer"
Echo Recursively searching %FFPath%
Echo=
For /F "Delims==" %%A In ('"Set File[ 2>Nul"') Do Set "%%A="
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=]" %%A In (
    '"Dir /B/S/A-D-S-L "%FFPath%\*.txt" 2>Nul|Find /N /V """') Do (
    Echo %%A] %%B
    Set "File%%A]=%%B"
)
Echo=
Set /P "#=Select file by number: "
Echo=
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ('"Set File[%#%] 2>Nul"') Do (
    Echo Copying %%B to %NewPath%&Echo= 
    Copy /Y "%%B" "%NewPath%"
    GoTo :End
)
Echo Invalid number selected   
:End
Echo=
Pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delayed expansion to get the file name assigned to the variable correctly.

```
SET NewFile=!file%selection%!
```

Remove the setlocal to disable delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that :

```bat
@ECHO OFF
:Main
cls
SET index=1
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET FFPath="C:\Scripts - Backup Server\DKXpress_bkp"
SET "NewPath=C:\DKServer"
ECHO Recursively searching %FFPath% 
echo.

FOR /F "delims=" %%f in ('DIR %FFPath%\*.txt /a:-d /s /b') DO (
    SET filepath[!index!]=%%f
    ECHO [!index!] - %%~nxf - %%f
    SET /A index=!index!+1
)
echo(
echo select file by number :
set /p Input=""
For /L %%i in (1,1,%index%) Do (
    If "%INPUT%" EQU "%%i" (
        ECHO Copying "!filepath[%%i]!" to "!NewPath!"
        COPY /Y "!filepath[%%i]!" "!NewPath!"
    )
) 
echo Copying another file ? (Y = Yes or N = No) ?
set /p input2=""
If /I "!input2!"=="Y" (
    goto :Main
) else (
    goto :eof
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked but without the file path in the file list.