# Create a numbered list based on a given list of strings

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, command-line, cmd

windows cmd batch

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Dog
Cat
Frog
Bat
Bird
Mouse
```

I want to attribute a number to each string, each line.

So that it becomes

```
1 Dog
2 Cat
3 Frog
4 Bat
5 Bird
6 Mouse
```

Then I want to ask the user to **input a number**, and then have the corresponding string stored in the variable.

So if the user inputs 1, then the variable is set to the string Dog
So when the user inputs 1 the program stores/outputs Dog

`set /p var1="number? "` so var1 becomes the string, not the number.

This does the first part of the task kinda, but now I need the second part, storing the strings in avariable.

```
@echo off
set TEXT_T="list.txt"

set /a c=0

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%i in (%TEXT_T%) do (
  set /a c=c+1

  echo !c! %%i 
)
endlocal
pause
```

Here below is an updated answer, thanks to LotPings.

With a small tweak to ask for the folder by string

This provides an easier way to use Megatools from CMD

https://megatools.megous.com/man/megals.html
https://github.com/megous/megatools

```
@echo off

:start:

megals /Root/

set /p var1="dir? " & megals /Root/%%var1%%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('megals -n /Root/%%var1%% ^|findstr
/n "." ') do (
set Link[%%A]=%%B
Echo %%A %%B
)

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('megals -n -e /Root/%%var1%% ^|findstr
/n "." ') do (
set Link[%%A]=%%B
)

set /p choice=Select #:
Call Set Link=%%Link[%choice%]%%

set "trimmedlink="
for %%h in (%Link%) do if not defined trimmedlink set "trimmedlink=%%h"
Megadl %trimmedlink% && goto :start:

pause
```

**Edit**: Had to trim `%Link%` to just the first word, i.e just the link

The output of `Megals -e /Root/misc` looks like this:
The asterisk are the unique link ids for the files

```
                                                    /Root/misc
   https://mega.nz/#!********!********************* /Root/misc/File1
   https://mega.nz/#!********!********************* /Root/misc/File2
   https://mega.nz/#!********!********************* /Root/misc/File3
```

With the batch script above it looks like:

```
1 File1
2 File2
3 File3
Select #:  <------input file number
```

**Edit2** number listing is fixed

**Edit3** Parentheses in filenames crash the program
i.e

```
1 File(1)
```

The chosen file number then gets passed to `Magadl` as the corresponding link
`Megadl Link`

The batch script allows you to download the link by just entering the corresponding file number so you don't have to type out the long link id in a standard cmd window.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49564553/edit) to include the code you have written or tried, _(this isn't a free code to order service)_.

Comment: Also please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to properly ask questions.

Comment: Definitely take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: Run `choice /?`, also search this site for existing answers to your menu problem.

Comment: I added the code so far, I think my question is fairly clear now.

Comment: @Compo, look like the same concept as one of your previous [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49482583/1417694)

Comment: What about this to do the numbering: `find /N /V "" "list.txt"` or `findstr /N /R "^" "list.txt"`?

Comment: @jwdonahue, I'm afraid `choice` might be difficult to handle in case there are more than 9 list entries...

Comment: Would have to use the alphabet if you wanted to use choice.

Comment: Are you now wanting to list the number and the filename, or just the filename? _Why ask somebody to type in a string when they could simply enter a number?_.  So the end user will be given a listing of directories, and will type in their choice which will invoke the link. Do you want to list the filename as it appears or the filename only, _without the initial parent_?

Comment: The folders don't need to be numbered, they are entered as strings. Only the files in the folders need to be numbered.

When the files are listed by `Megals`, /Root/dir is shown at the top of the file list, so it gets assigned the number 1 by the list, but number 1 should really be  assigned to the first file instead.

Comment: The current code above outputs
`Number Link /Path/Filename`

Although `Number /Path/Filename Link` would be more readable.  
That might be tricky to do, and not totally necessary.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to run `MegaLs -n /Root/Dir` for the File selection then run `MegaLs -e /Root/Dir/File` to retrieve the Link after that?

Comment: `-n` doesn't return the file links, just the filenames. 
`%Link%` needs to be assigned the links numbered.

Comment: @JimJamil, I know, what it does, I read the pages you linked to! `-n` will return the file names only, which is what you need for your menu. Then you run `-e` to retrieve only the respective link using `/Root/typeddirectory/chosenfilename`.

Comment: Okay thanks, take a look at the updated code, seems to work, and it also numbers the file list correctly. File 1 is listed as 1

Comment: Edit: the files are still numbered incorrectly, `megals -n` numbers them correctly File 1 is listed as 1. However `megals -e` in the background is still listing File 1 as 2 in the list, you just don't see it because only `-n` is echoed.

Comment: Any idea how to fix that? I tried `tokens=2 `and `skip=1` neither work for some reason.

Comment: **Fixed** by using `-n -e`

Comment: The program crashes if the filenames have ( ) type brackets. @Compo

Comment: Any ideas on the brackets issue? @LotPings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use megals output directly and avoid delayedexpansion (which removes the `!`)
Findstr /n will do the numbering.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('megals -e /Root/ ^|findstr /n "." ') do (
  set Item[%%A]=%%B
  Echo %%A %%B
)
set /p choice=Select #:
Call Echo Choice:%%Item[%choice%]%%
```

Using a (pseudo-)call with doubled percent signs is an old fashioned method of realizing delayed expansion without the problem with the `!`.

In programming/scripting you need to adapt techniques to fit your needs.

Without knowing the exact output of your megatools,
this could do the job :

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('megals -e /Root/ ^|findstr /n "." ') do (
  set Folder[%%A]=%%B
  Echo %%A %%B
)
set /p choice=Select #:
Call Set Folder=%%Folder[%choice%]%%

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('megals -e %Folder% ^|findstr /n "." ') do (
  set Link[%%A]=%%B
  Echo %%A %%B
)
set /p choice=Select #:
Call Set Link=%%Link[%choice%]%%

megadl %Link%
```

As compo advised, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19277114) your question to contain all necessary information - don't force others to gather it from unnecessary answer and comments.

Comment: I still need to give the link to Megadl

Comment: See my enhanced answer.

Comment: I'll try to clean up the post a bit, sorry this is my first post here.

Ideally it would be good to have the program prompt for the folder by name (string) instead of number, only the listed files within the folders need to use the number for input. Megals automatically lists the folders by name, so it would be more intuitive for the user to enter the folder name, get the list of files, and then ask for the file number.

Cmd has no easy copy paste being the cause of all this lol.
I'll take a look at your code here.

Comment: If you check mark `Quick-edit-mode` and `insert-mode` in system menu/ settings/options tab of your cmd window copy and paste will work (in recent win10 also Ctrl+V  to paste) dragging with the mouse to mark and right-click to copy. You can also redirect output directly to the clipboard with i.e.`dir  |clip.exe`

Comment: This is on a Win7 system, so cmd is still a bit awkward for that.
Pipe to Clip is handy though.

Comment: I updated the first post with an ask folder by name method, as I mentioned it will list the files in the directory, but if there are 13 files, file 13 will be numbered as 14 by the list generator, this is because the Root/Directory gets listed as 1, because of how Megals lists the output.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an array:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set TEXT_T="list.txt"

set /a c=0

FOR /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%i in (%TEXT_T%) do (
  set /a c=c+1
  echo !c! %%i 
  set string[!c!]=%%i
)

set /P number=Enter number:
echo !string[%number%]!

pause
```

For further details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: Thanks that's great. I also was wondering about reading from command output instead of txt file.

Comment: Just enclose the command between apostrophes: `FOR /F "tokens=1" %%i in ('TYPE %TEXT_T%') do (`

Answer (score 0):

What about making the output of a command into a list, instead of a text file into a list?

so the line with var1 here would be turned into a numbered list (the files listed in that directory), and Var2 is the number the users enters to create the returned string that gets passed to a command. i.e
https://megatools.megous.com/man/megals.html

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(megals -e /Root/) <--------list all folders in root
(set /p var1="dir? " && megals -e /Root/!var1!) <-- select folder + list files
(set /p var2="Megalink? " && Megadl !var2!) <--- enter the file name for download
ENDLOCAL
pause
```

I want to be able to enter a number for the download, instead of the long file name. So this way the user can enter the number that corresponds to the link that they want to download. So if they enter 1 then the program does Megadl Dog

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

megals -e /Root/

set /p var1="dir? "

megals -e /Root/!var1! > rlist.txt

set TEXT_T="rlist.txt"

set /a c=0

FOR /F "tokens=1 usebackq" %%i in (%TEXT_T%) do (
set /a c=c+1
echo !c! %%i 
set string[!c!]=%%i
)

set /P number=Enter number:
Megadl !string[%number%]!
Endlocal
pause
```

This kills the first part of the link because it removes everything in between and including exclamations. !dasasdasd!
all megalinks start with #!something!

Comment: No need to use delayed expansion with the `var1` variable.

Comment: @JimJamil, is the content of `megals -e /Root/directory`, exactly the same as your original `list.txt` file shows? If not, please edit your question to provide the new requirement and the content of that command.

Comment: It's a list of megalinks, one on each line
https://megatools.megous.com/man/megatools.html#_tools_overview

Comment: @JimJamil, that doesn't show the output, I need to see it, if you require advice on parsing it for use in a menu and associated variable system.

Comment: Th output of Megals -e /Root/anime

A list of links like
    https://mega.nz/#Link There's four blank columns before each link for some reason too.

Comment: Have you clicked on that link? where's it supposed to take me? Why could you not just run `megals -e /Root/` and paste the output, _as code_, into your question?

Comment: So you've revisited the question and edited it, but still haven't, corrected the link or provided the output of that command. _Your question has attracted so much more attention than most on here, we're trying to help you and you're making it difficult._

Comment: I added the output to first post.

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work

I need output of Call Echo %%Item[%choice%]%% passed to Megadl

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in ('megals -e /Root/anime ^|findstr /n "." ') do (
set Item[%%A]=%%B
Echo %%A %%B
)
set /p choice=Select #:
Call Echo %%Item[%choice%]%%

for /F "tokens=*" (`%%Item[%choice%]%%`) do (
set "var1=%%A"
Megadl !Var1!
)
pause
```